# Need script to kill python process with low CPU usage

Tags: python, ps, process-management

I've created a very large and complex python program and I now know it has a serious bug that I'm having a very hard time pinning down. I'm using this code in a production environment so I need a stop-gap measure to implement until I find and correct my coding issue. I need to create a bash script that I can use to check for CPU usage of my python program and kill it if it's consistently below x%. Once killed it will automatically restart on it's own.

I'm using the following to get my PID and %CPU

```
$ ps -eo pid -eo pcpu -eo command |grep python |grep pycode.py
```

> 2940 71.9 python pycode.py

How can I check %cpu, which is 71.9 above, against x% cpu and then kill the PID if needed.

Also, the python program does not go runaway nor does it die. It simply drops to below 5% cpu and stays there and the UI freezes. I'm new to bash so I really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a crude attempt:

```
read -r pid cpu rest < <(ps -eo pid -eo pcpu -eo command |grep python |grep pycode.py)
if (( ${cpu%.*} < 5 )) ; then
    kill -TERM $pid
fi
```

We use `${cpu%.*}` to truncate it to an integer, since bash can't handle floats. This only runs once; if you want to keep it going, put it on a cron job, or put it in a loop with `sleep 5` or whatever.

Comment: I get an error when running the above:
 line 2: ((: < 5 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< 5 ")

Comment: What's the value of `$cpu` when you do that? If you ran it from the shell, it should still be in the environment, or you could add `echo $cpu` right before the `if` statement. The obvious issue would be if `$cpu` was empty, as would be the case if `pycode.py` was not running when the code was run.

Comment: I found it. Thank you. It works and I understand it, so I can make changes as needed.